# using here document and pipeline of sh at the same time

Tags: sh, heredoc

I'm using here document of sh to run some commands. now I want to parse the output of  those commands using awk. However, everytime I execute it, I get the output of the command append with something like this "% No such child process"

This is how my script looks like.

```
#!/bin/sh
com = "sudo -u username /path/of/file -l"
$com <<EOF | awk '{print $0}'
Commands.
.
.
.
EOF
```

How am I going to use heredoc and pipeline without appending that unwanted string? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable assignment is wrong in a couple of ways. First, you aren't actually assigning a variable; you're trying to run a command named `com` whose arguments are `=` and a string `"sudo ..."`. Spaces must not be used on either side of the `=`:

```
com="sudo ..."
```

Second, command lines should not be stored in a variable; the shell's parser can only make that work they way you intend for very simple commands. Type the command out in full, or use a shell function.

```
com () {
    sudo -u username /path/to/file -l
}

com <<EOF | awk '{print $0}'
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem, check :

```
$ cat <<EOF | awk '{print $1}'
a b c
1 2 3
EOF
a
1
```

Comment: it's weird. because if you  print $0, it gives you the output plus something like this at the end "% No such child process 4330"